# Node.js: child_process.spawn no output standard output unless 'inherit'

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdout, stderr, child-process

I'm trying to capture [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) from a `spawn`ed `child_process` in Node.js (0.10.29).

Right now I'm just trying with [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29).

The following code doesn't print (but does ping)

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var util = require('util')

var ping = spawn('ping', ['127.0.0.1'], {stdio: 'pipe'});

ping.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    util.print(data);
})

ping.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    util.print(data);
})
```

If I change `stdio: 'pipe'` to `stdio: 'inherit'` and get rid of the `stdout/stderr` hooks like so:

```
var ping = spawn('ping', ['127.0.0.2'], {stdio: 'inherit'});

// ping.stdout.on('data', function(data){
//     util.print(data);
// })

// ping.stderr.on('data', function(data){
//     util.print(data);
// })
```

I get

```
PING 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

If I change the address from `127.0.0.2` to `127.0.0.1`, which I know will respond to the pings and use the original code I get

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.152 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
```

Why are stdout/stderr not firing `data` events when the ping isn't `pinging` or `inheriting`?

Comment: what do you mean by ` doesn't print (but does ping)` ?

Comment: The `ping` process runs and pings localhost but the node program doesn't print to stdout.

Comment: but I copied your code and it's working fine I think.

Comment: @Mritunjay - which section of code? The trouble code is the first bit of code with 127.0.0.2

Comment: sorry I just copied & pasted first part with 127.0.0.1

Comment: but for that also it's working. I'm using `node v0.11.13` unstable.

Comment: Anyone try with v0.10.25 or 29?

Comment: I changed it to `var ping = spawn('ping', ['-v', '-c', '10', '127.0.0.2'], {stdio: 'pipe'});`

and after the ping runs through all ten requests and ends it outputs

`PING 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8

--- 127.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss`

Comment: Also @Mritunjay I just tried it on 0.11.13 and couldn't get it to print

Comment: are you getting warning like `util.print: Use console.log instead`. Try with console.log once.

Comment: Even with console.log. Basically I've narrowed it down - Node doesn't seem to get stdout until the process has finished in some cases - others it can get a live update. Not sure what the difference between these two are.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? A way to force stdout to be parsed in a stream instead of waiting until the command finishes?

Comment: It actually works fine in latest node version. Probably, you'd just better update yours!

Comment: Can you update you node.js version?

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of issue fixes as well as feature improvements with respect to console printing, on the lines of chunking and buffering. As the issue isn't reproducible any more, I would assume that this could be due to one of the underdocumented behaviors of the then Node.js, based on how many bytes of data is available for printing.